# Best practice for navigation bars on modern websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I've been really struggling to find a good answer for this question... I have many html pages and one navigation bar. I want to include the navigation bar on all pages, as would be good for consistency... Now, it goes against everything I've learned to duplicate the html code to make the navigation bar.

I've seen of a couple solutions to this problem:

- Use jQuery to `$('nav').load('nav.html')` load the navbar code into your document.
- Use jQuery to `$('#content).load('content.html')` load the content into your document.
- Use iFrames. No. (Unless I should?).
- Natural javascript variants of the first two...
- Just write the entire thing in javascript and include it in the head...

I have used the first one but it ruined my page structure. I've used the second one but I am having a lot of issues with styling as I have no idea when scripts are loaded if they are deferred in the `head`, put in the `body`, or if they are included in the html page that gets loaded in, etc.

**My question is...** what is the best practice to include a consistent navigation bar on all pages, without repeating the navbar code (unless that is the best practice).

Comment: Have you considered using a templating engine of some sort?

Comment: For simple and minimal amount of pages, just reuse the code by including the nav file. You mentioned multiple pages, most likely dynamic content, so a template engine as suggested would take care of that. [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) for PHP.

Comment: @AleksG Are templating engines pretty standard and future proof? I find it bizarre that I haven't seen one until now. They seem to do what I want. Is it easy to extend such a thing to say, highlight the active page, or are the items included easily accessible by JS on DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, a templating engine is used during development to generate the html files, for example using Gulp and Nunjucks. The actual files that get put on the server are not written by me directly, but generated with this tool. This way the JS that I may defer in my head will run with the complete DOM when the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered, unlike if I were to load something on the fly with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was "answered" in the comments of my question, but I figured I'll add it here...

Templating engines provide a way to "generate" an HTML file before putting it on a hosting server. This way you don't need to do any HTML inserts and have funky script loading issues. The nav bar will essentially be repeat code, but you won't be writing it yourself, the templating engine will.

A nice tutorial I found for Nunjucks can be found [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/nunjucks-with-gulp/). There are many more but this one felt like exactly what I needed.